# Base and peak tuning in Spec2017 config

Tags: c, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

I'm compiling Spec2017 intspeed and fpspeed for simulation on gem5. By looking at the default configs, I've seen that `-fno-strict-aliasing` is enabling for all benchmarks by default. This is highly undesirable for what I'm trying to research and so I want to disable it on all benchmarks besides `600.perl_s`, which needs it to compile correctly.

There's a section in the config called 'Peak Tuning Flags' which overviews how to set flags for specific benchmarks, but I'm unsure about the difference or even meanings of base and peak runs and how to know which version I'm running. I'm also unsure if when enabling peak tuning I need to specify flags for each and every benchmark, or if unspecified benchmarks will fallback to the default (so, I could just remove `-fno-strict-aliasing` from the default flags and only set it for perl).

Is anyone able to explain how to do what I want to achieve here?

Comment: Spec2017 isn't free. So how are we to check how it's compiled and answer this?